# Addition of unsigned and int giving unexpected values

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
unsigned a = 10;
int b = -15;
cout<<a+b;
return 0;
}
```

Is giving the output 4294967291. Can't figure out why?

Comment: 4294967291 = 0xFFFFFFFB

Comment: Without knowing more, I would guess that the expression `a+b` is being treated as `unsigned`. But I do not know a parsing rule that would explain why.

Comment: Try casting: `cout << "result: " << (int)a + b << endl;`